# Meaning of "neck is forfeited"?

Tags: word-usage

What does "neck is forfeited" mean in the following sentence?

> "Human nature is a strange mixture, Watson. You see that even a villain and murderer can inspire such affection that his brother turns to suicide when he learns that his **neck is forfeited**."

Comment: The pronoun antecedents are very unclear in that sentence, making it hard to understand.  (I vaguely recall that Doyle was prone to such confusing sentence structure.)  I presume it to mean that a villain can inspire affection in a brother such that the brother will behave in a suicidal manner when the villain is under threat of execution.  ("Neck is forfeited" is something of a euphemism for hanging.)

Comment: Thanks, actually pronouns also confused me. But your explanation seems to be valid. By the way, this excerpt is from Sherlock Holmes story "The Adventure of the Stockbroker's clerk"

Answer (score 1):

Someone's **neck is forfeit** when they are **to be hanged**. The villain has learnt that he is to be executed and his brother is so distraught that he is driven to suicide.

Forfeit can be used to mean that ownership is involuntary transferred to another and in this case onwership is transferred to the hangman.

This is what Holmes finds strange: that someone so villainous can yet be so loved that when their brother learns that the villain is to be executed, he is so distraught that the brother kills himself.

Comment: There is also the expression 'get it in the neck', meaning severe punishment. *He'll get it in the neck if he is caught*. The OED does link it back to the practice of hanging (last execution in Britain in 1962) and prior to that beheading. So the neck could be 'forfeited' to the executioner's rope or axe.